# In Jina, when is `uses_after` in `Pod` applied?

Tags: python, microservices

Is the `uses_after` keyword in a pod tells me, what should happen as an aggregation method on all the results of shards defined in `uses`, that ran in parallel? So it should have access to all the results, that were given by the pods defined under `uses`?

So the `tail_pea` should get all the results of the parallel peas as for example in the `ReduceAllDriver` in the hello-world example, right?

Answer (score 0):

First, let me clarify three `uses` here. `uses` is defined at Pea level; `uses-after` and `uses-before` are defined at Pod level.

So when you define `uses-after`, `uses-before` and `uses` at Pod level, the assignment would be:

- `head_pea` gets `uses_before`,
- `tail_pea` gets `uses_after`
- all replicas (aka parallel peas) get `uses`

In the current `ReduceDriver` implementation, `__call__` is called 4 times but `reduce` is called only one time.